# Passing Search Input to Javascript Without Input Button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following html form that I'm trying to submit to javascript without using any buttons. Enter the query and press enter should complete the form submission.

I get an error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.form.query')". If I remove 'this.form.query' from the onsubmit(), then the function gets called. What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to pass the query to the JS function?

```
<form onsubmit="searchWiki(this.form.query)">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" name="query" />
</form>
```

My JS function is below

```
function searchWiki(data) {
var script = document.createElement('script');
console.log(data);
script.src = '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=apple%20inc&callback=wikiData';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};
```

**Update:**
Thanks to everyone's help. Below is my updated code:

HTML

```
<form id="search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" name="query" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function searchWiki(data) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    console.log(data);
    script.src = `//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=${data}&callback=wikiData`;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchWiki(encodeURIComponent(this.query.value));
})
```

Comment: try `onsubmit="searchWiki(this.query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is already the form, so this.form gives undefined.

You either need to pass the input directly: this.query or pass the value of the input:

```
<form onsubmit="searchWiki(this.query.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adding an `id` to your input and use `document.getElementById`

```
<form onsubmit="searchWiki(document.getElementById('query').value)">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" id="query" name="query" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, if using jQuery is possible:

```js
function searchWiki(data) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  console.log(data);
  script.src = '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=apple%20inc&callback=wikiData';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  searchWiki($(this).serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" name="query" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding preventDefault() which stopped the browser from reloading the page and clearing the console with each submit. This is working better than my original implementation. Although my original goal was to get a better understanding of javascript without jQuery obfuscating the inner workings of the scripting language.

Answer (score -1):

Try not using 'this' in the DOM.